# How can you use the Levi-Civita symbol (index notation) to derive an expression for $(\hat{r}\times\nabla)\cdot(\hat{r} \times\nabla)$?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, vectors, mathematical-physics

I was studying the expression for the momentum operator in quantum mechanics, and found a text that described this operator in spherical coordinates. However, during the derivation, the text states that:

$$(\hat{r}\times\nabla)\boldsymbol{\cdot}(\hat{r} \times\nabla)=\nabla^2-\frac{1}{r^2}\frac{\partial}{\partial r}\left(r^2\frac{\partial}{\partial r}\right) \tag{1}$$

Previously I have used the [Binet-Cauchy identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binet%E2%80%93Cauchy_identity) which states;

$$(\textbf{a} \times \textbf{b})\boldsymbol{\cdot}(\textbf{c} \times \textbf{d}) = (\textbf{a} \boldsymbol{\cdot} \textbf{b})(\textbf{c} \boldsymbol{\cdot} \textbf{d}) - (\textbf{a} \boldsymbol{\cdot} \textbf{d}) (\textbf{b} \boldsymbol{\cdot} \textbf{c})$$

Applying this rule to (1), we get:

$$(\hat{r}\times\nabla)\boldsymbol{\cdot}(\hat{r} \times\nabla)=\nabla^2-(\hat{r}\boldsymbol{\cdot}\nabla)(\nabla \boldsymbol{\cdot}\hat{r})$$

However, I cannot go further with this expression, and I struggle to get (1) using Binet-Cauchy. I therefore choose to use the Levi-Civita symbol (index notation) to derive the correct answer, but I want help to derive (1) using this formalism.

Eq. (1) is used during the derivation of the squared angular momentum operator. The angular momentum operator is given as;

$$\hat{L}=\hat{R} \times \hat{P}=(-i \hbar r)\hat{r} \times \boldsymbol{\nabla}$$

And the square of the angular momentum operator is thus [using (1)];

$$\hat{L}^2=(- \hbar^2 r^2)(\hat{r} \times \boldsymbol{\nabla})(\hat{r} \times \boldsymbol{\nabla})=(-\hbar^2r^2)\left[\nabla^2-\frac{1}{r^2}\frac{\partial}{\partial r}\left(r^2\frac{\partial}{\partial r}\right)\right]$$

Now since we know the laplace operator in spherical coordinates, $\nabla^2=\frac{1}{r^2}\frac{\partial}{\partial r}\left(r^2\frac{\partial}{\partial r}\right)+\frac{1}{r^2 \text{sin}\theta}\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}\left(\text{sin}\theta\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta}\right)+\frac{1}{r^2\text{sin}^2\theta}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial\phi^2}$, we can easily see that the $r$-component disappears in the expression of the squared angular momentum operator, leaving;

$$\hat{L}^2=(-\hbar^2r^2)\left[\frac{1}{r^2 \text{sin}\theta}\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}\left(\text{sin}\theta\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta}\right)+\frac{1}{r^2\text{sin}^2\theta}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial\phi^2}\right]$$

But this all rests on eq. (1) to be true, so how can we use the index-notation to derive (1)?

Comment: It might be relevant that right side is the purely angular part of the Laplacian.

Comment: Have you tried showing this by using $\nabla$ in spherical coordinates?

Comment: This question is about math, not physics.

Comment: The BCI doesn't always work when differential operators are involved, as its proof makes commutativity assumptions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Recall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system) that
$$
 \frac{\partial}{\partial r}= \hat r\cdot \nabla,\\
\left [ \frac{\partial}{\partial r}, \hat r\right ]=0.
$$

You then simply [slug through](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levi-Civita_symbol#Index_and_symbol_values)
$$(\hat{r}\times\nabla)\boldsymbol{\cdot}(\hat{r} \times\nabla)\\
= \epsilon^{ijk}\epsilon_{imn}\frac{r_j}{r}\partial_k \left (\frac{r^m}{r}\partial^n\right)\\
=(\delta^j_m \delta^k_n - \delta^j_n \delta^k_m)\left (\delta^m_k\frac{r_j}{r^2}\partial^n- \frac{r_jr_kr^m}{r^4}\partial^n+\frac{r_jr^m}{r^2}\partial_k\partial^n\right )\\
= \partial^n \partial_n - \left (\frac{r^jr^n}{r^2}\partial _j \partial_n+\frac{2}{r} \frac{\partial}{\partial r}  \right)\\
=\nabla^2-\left (\frac{r^n}{r}\frac{\partial}{\partial r} \partial_n+\frac{2}{r} \frac{\partial}{\partial r}  \right)= \nabla^2-\left (   \frac{\partial^2}{\partial r^2}+\frac{2}{r} \frac{\partial}{\partial r} \right)\\
=\nabla^2-\frac{1}{r^2}\frac{\partial}{\partial r}\left(r^2\frac{\partial}{\partial r}\right) . $$

Comment: I will sit down and learn the Levi-Civita notation now to make life easier. Thank you!

Comment: I have a question regarding the second equality sign. I know the 'contracted epsilon identity' from the link you sent, and I get the laplace operator, but I get a second term, and I do not know how this term disappears. I think the Levi-Civita formalism is very powerful, and I really want to learn it.

Comment: Inserted  your intermediate step. Note the middle term in the lagging parenthesis vanishes for antisymmetry&symmetry of *jk*.

Comment: Thank you. The substitution of the epsilons makes perfect sense since the indices are cyclic. I also understand why the middle term vanishes. I almost get the result after the third equality sign, but I have the expression $\frac{r_j}{r^2}\partial^n$ and to get the correct result, this expression should be $-\frac{1}{r}\partial_r$, but how is this possible? What is $r_j\partial^n$?

Comment: You have four terms, two of which combine to one, so three correct terms on the target expression. Make sure you contract indices properly and utilize the topmost identity.

Comment: How can we interpret $\partial_k r^m$? Is it $\delta_{km}$?

Comment: Of course it is. This is what it *means*.

Comment: Okay, I understand the derivation now. I had misunderstood the kronecker-delta notation, but knowing that $\delta_{jj}=3$ and $\delta_{jm}\delta_{kn}\delta_{mk}=\delta_{jn}$ helped me derive the answer. Although this rests on viewing kronecker-delta representation as $\delta_{jm}=\delta_m^j$ (I hope this is correct as I could not find any confirmation when researching.)

Comment: My last question is for the equality $\frac{r^n}{r}\partial_r\partial_n=\partial_r^2$. For this to make sense to me would mean that $\frac{r^n}{r}\partial_r\partial_n=\frac{r^n}{r}\partial_n\partial_r=\partial_r^2$, but this would violate the rule that $\partial_n$ and $\partial_r$ are operators (So why can we move them around)?

Comment: Indeed, for a flat space as here, upper and lower indices are equivalent. The second identity provided, provable from WP, allows you to commute $\hat r$ with $\partial_r$, so as to fuse it with the rightmost gradient: $ (\hat r \partial _r)\cdot \nabla=\partial_r (\hat r \cdot \nabla)$.

Comment: Ah I see! So we have $\frac{r^n}{r}\partial_r\partial_n=\frac{r}{r}[\hat{r}\partial_r]\cdot\nabla=\partial_r[\hat{r}\cdot\nabla]=\partial_r^2$ because $[r^n\partial_r]\partial_n=[\textbf{r}\partial_r]\cdot\nabla$